# Is there a man page for php pear from php-pear package?

Tags: 13.10, php, manpage

I'm searching for man page documentation or alternatives for the php-pear package on Ubtunu 13.10. Concretely I'm stuck with the following issues (besides not finding the man page where I believe to find answers to the following questions myself, so please consider answering them right here or sharing links to resources other than the man page):

- How to react to output `Did not download optional dependencies: pear/System_Command, use --alldeps to download automatically` (there seems to be no `--alldeps` argument; tried all kind of combinations)?
- Where are config files of PEAR on Ubuntu? I'm looking for the cache directory.

Comment: hello have you tried it like this? `sudo pear install --alldeps phing/phing` just asking to make sure